# Docker for Load testing

Tags: docker, jmeter, containers, jmeter-plugins

I wanted to use docker for JMeter distributed Load testing environment. I would like to know if there are any disadvantages, especially the impact on load-testing using containers wrt latency, network  issues ,memory as when we use docker containers as Load generator environment.
Kindly share your ideas / links if any .

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Like every other Docker image, you must have administrator privileges to run it, and the options and permissions necessary to extract results are potentially complex.

Comment: Thanks David for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since the load generator is a container, it doesn't have any impact on the result; since, the Actual load is happening on the other hosts.

Comment: Thanks Hari for the response

Answer (score 2):

If you have limited physical (or virtual) hardware using containers in general and Docker in particular is not the best idea as containers have its virtualization cost hence you will be able to utilize host machine resources more efficiently if you run JMeter directly, without extra layer.

However if you want to scale the tests using container management solution like [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) or [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) with possibility to allocate machines to run containers on it might make sense.

Check out [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker/) article for example JMeter setup in [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the valuable comment

Comment: Is it possible to run multiple containers on one machine? If I want to create an image for jmeter master and 3 slaves,do I only need Jmeter and Docker or do I also have to utilize some orchestration software like Kubernetes or Docker Swarm?